# Accessing Nextjs public folder file on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, service-worker, manifest.json

I have my service worker, manifest and other files in public folder which does not get in .next folder and does not end in s3 bucket.
How can I access the files on prod build, though it works fine on local build

I tried a few hacks, nothing seem to work

Comment: Share the app code you used to access the public files.